# Angular 2 Observables and Change detection - How to get one component to retrieve a value, set by another component in a service?

Tags: angularjs, angular, reactive-programming, observable, subscribe

I think I'm overlooking something very fundamental, and I've been banging my head for a couple of days now. I'm new to Angular and reactive programming.

So, I have one service and two components.

In my `versionService.ts` I have a helper method which allows components to set a `currentVersion` in a `_dataStore`.

```
private _dataStore: {
    currentVersion: any
};
currVersionStream$: Subject<Version>;

constructor(public http: Http) {
    this.currVersionStream$ = new BehaviorSubject<Version>(null);
    this._dataStore = {
        currentVersion: null
    };
}
public setCurrentVersion(v: Version): void {
    if (v != null) {
        this._dataStore.currentVersion = v;            
        this.currVersionStream$.next(this._dataStore.currentVersion);
    }
}
```

Then in my component `select-version.component.ts`, through a (click) event from the view/template, I use the `setCurrentVersion` helper method from the `VersionService.ts` to store the cliked on version.

In `select.version.template.html`:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li *ngFor="#v of availableVersions" (click)="selectedVersion(v)">
        <a href="#">
            Version {{v.versionID}}
        </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">No version</a></li>
</ul>
```

In `version.component.ts`: Here I call on the method in the service.
**Update**: I inject versionService in both of my components.

```
    import {VersionService} from '../../services/services';

@Component({
        selector: 'select-version',
        templateUrl: 'app/component/selectVersion/select-version.template.html',
        providers: [VersionService]
    })

export class SelectVersionComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(public versionService: VersionService) {}

    public selectedVersion(v: Version) {
        console.log("SVC - set this version: " + v.versionID);
        this.versionService.setCurrentVersion(v);
    }
```

So, in my **second** component I want to retrieve the value set/stored in the service (`_dataStore`), and display it in its view/template (of my second component)

In my `second-component.template.html`:

```
<h2>{{selectedVersion}}</h2>
```

In my `second-component.ts`:
**Update:**

```
    import {VersionService} from '../../services/services';

@Component({
    selector: 'main-container',
    templateUrl: 'app/component/mainContainer/main-container.template.html',
    providers: [VersionService],
})

selectedVersion: any;

constructor(public versionService: VersionService) {
    this.versionService.currVersionStream$.subscribe((v) => {
        if(v != null) {
            this.selectedVersion = "Version" + v.versionID
        }
    }, error => console.error (error));
}
```

**Update:**
In my main component, app.component.ts:

```
import {SidebarComponent} from './component/sidebar/sidebar.component';
import {MainContainerComponent} from './component/mainContainer/main-container.component';


@Component({
    selector: 'init-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/app-component.template.html',
    directives: [SidebarComponent, MainContainerComponent],
})

export class AppComponent {
    constructor() {}
}
```

In my boot.ts:

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {AppComponent} from './app.component'
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http'

bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS])
     .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

What am I missing to be able to view the `currentVersion` in my template of the second component, and will it update each time a new value is set?
Thanks for any reply!

Comment: If you're injecting the service in each component each one will get a different instance. If those components are siblings, make sure to inject the Service in the parent component, once.

Comment: As Eric mentioned, it should be working as you expect.  Can you show how you are registering the service with the component? Are you passing it through the `providers` property (i.e. providers: [VersionService]), or are you setting it up when you bootstrap (i.e. bootstrap(AppComponent, [VersionService])? You should be doing the latter only (not both).

Comment: Ah ok, I was injecting the service in each component. I'll try to inject it in the main component instead. Thanks!

Comment: I had the same problem a couple of days ago, it was answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34978455/angular2-cannot-subscribe-to-custom-events-emitted-from-shared-service

Comment: It is working now! I injected the service in the main component. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To complement what Eric and pixelbits said, you don't share the same instance of the service. One instance is created per component since you use the `providers` attribute at this level.

If you want to know more about the hierarchical injection, you could have a look at this answer:

- [What's the best way to inject one service into another in angular 2 (Beta)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804298/whats-the-best-way-to-inject-one-service-into-another-in-angular-2-beta/34807397#34807397).

Hope it helps you,
Thierry